# requests doesn't close a connection after a REST command

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I am doing some quite simple REST API calls to a local server using python and requests, something like this

```
# Delete the sensor with the specified ID
def _deleteSensorById(self, id):
    URL = baseSensorsAPIsURL + "sensors/" + id

    response = requests.delete(URL)
    self._checkStatusCode(response)
    response.close()
```

My REST server is listening on port 5126, and after a call is correctly served, I can see a connection hanging...

```
  netstat -aon -p tcp | findstr :5126
  TCP    127.0.0.1:64495        127.0.0.1:5126         TIME_WAIT       0
```

This is despite adding the **response.close()** line...

How to properly close a request, avoiding this dangling connection?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is wrong? In your code sample, you merely close the response to a single request. I imagine you would still want the REST API to be able to server future requests?

Comment: I would like to close the hanging connection after the request has been served, i.e. I *do not* want to see that _TIME_WAIT_ entry in the netstat table...

Comment: If I Google 'netstat TIME_WAIT', I get: "If NetStat says a connection is in the TIME_WAIT state, it means the client has already disconnected. So if you see several connections in TIME_WAIT it is not a 'simultaneous' connection. It is common for a client to connect to the sever multiple times, generating several TIME_WAIT connections."

Comment: Isn't netstat merely showing that your REST API is listening on the port 5126? That is what you would want?

Comment: I am sending several requests, and I can see several lines (one per request...) in netstat.
I am puzzled by why these lines are there, since I am explicitly closing the connection. Most probably I'm not doing it in the proper way...

And no, the line showing that the server is running is different...

Comment: It doesn't seem to be important -> https://serverfault.com/questions/23385/huge-amount-of-time-wait-connections-says-netstat

Comment: It's not important unless you do _lots_ of requests and you run out of ports :/

Comment: Could that not be mitigated by lowering a timeout?